# Cloud foundry service broker - implementing REST endpoints

Tags: java, servlets, service, cloud

I have a general question on a topic I am starting to learn, but having difficulty imagining the specific implementations for.

I want to implement a service broker for Cloud Foundry.  The service broker API is as follows:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/api.html

I'm new to web programming.  I have worked with web applications where I publish html files which reference servlets.  But I'm not sure how one goes about implementing, for example:

Route

GET /v2/catalog

I was wondering if someone could give a high level rundown of what is involved in doing this.  How do I implement a "path" like this?  Let's say I wrote a servlet which hangs around at site.com/Servlet.  The service broker will call site.com/Servlet/v2/catalog.  How would my Servlet understand this?  Would this URI even direct to my Servlet as written?  I'm using Liberty (Websphere), but any answer would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the Spring framework - website at https://spring.io/. It might take a bit of learning to understand what Spring is (it has many components that do different things), but Spring provides tools to make writing REST APIs very easy. Spring is well documented, has tons of users, and is quite modern.

For a REST API in Spring, you'd define a "Controller" class that controls incoming HTTP calls to the port you program is listening on.

For your concerns about how your programs understands a GET call to a particular endpoint - Spring provides the @RequestMapping annotation to do exactly this task. Within a class you've annotated with @Controller, you will have the @RequestMapping annotation over a method like this:

```
@Controller
public class CloudFoundryController {
...

   @RequestMapping(value = {"/servlet/v2/catalog"}, method = RequestMethod.GET
   public HttpResponse getV2Catalogue() {
      ...
   }
}
```

When this application detects an HTTP GET request with "/servlet/v2/catalog" as the URL endpoint, then Spring will ensure that the getV2Catalogue() method is called. When the method returns, Spring sends back, over the network, an object of whatever type you've defined in the method header as an http response.

Building a REST service with Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/